# What is the difference between these minikube commands?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

What is the difference between `minikube start` and `minikube create cluster`?

Do they both create a cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Minikube start`, start the cluster with the name `minikube` by default

`minikube create cluster` which version are you using ? No commands exist actually in official documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/

[image]

Comment: It was on my professor's notes: https://github.com/dsalomoni/bdp2-2021/tree/main/cloud_automation, however in the slides he did write minikube start.

Comment: yes, you are right. there is no create command maybe it's title `create cluster`